# Why would I give the execute permission for txt file (non-script) file

Tags: permissions, executable

In [this article](https://its.unc.edu/research-computing/techdocs/how-to-use-unix-and-linux-file-permissions/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20also%20use%20the%20letters%20r%2C%20w%2C%20and%20x%20to%20set%20read%2C%20write%2C%20and%20execute%20permissions%20and%20the%20letters%20u%2C%20g%2C%20o%2C%20and%20a%20to%20specify%20user%2C%20group%2C%20other%20or%20all%3A) we see x permission is added to myfile.txt:

```
mode  of  `myfile.txt'  changed  to  0751  (rwxr-x--x)
```

What is execute permission in the context of non-script file?

When would I need execute only permission for non-script file?
`--x`

When would I need read and execute permission for non-script file?
`r-x`

Comment: You probably wouldn't. Unless you know you need to for some good reason. But just reading something silly off a random guide online isn't much of a good reason. Most likely they just used `myfile.txt` as the example filename instead of just `myfile`, because some people might expect filenames to have that extension part with a dot [citation needed].

Comment: @ilkkachu in this case, when I arrange an ssh key pair connection, I can set permission 700 for .ssh folder on my server and omit the recommendation of setting 600 permission for authorized_keys. Why? Because it's already 700 since it's in .ssh folder. Changing authorized_keys permissions for 600 (depriving the x rights) gives absolutely nothing in terms of security hardening. Am I right? I found it as a standard recommendation: 700 for .ssh and 600 for authorized_keys.

Comment: 600 is still useful in case that file is hard linked to another directory that is more accessible, or for the day you move or copy that file.

Comment: @AndrewAnderson, mostly the `x` bit is just irrelevant for data files. **Unless** there's some program that explicitly checks for it, e.g. Apache has the [XBitHack directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html#xbithack) that tells it to use the execute permission to check if the file should be parsed for server-side includes. Making `authorized_keys` group-writable would be a bit suspect, and making it world-writable even in a restricted dir would get it rejected by the SSH server. It doesn't look like it'd check for the `x` bit though.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the execute (`x`) permission has no effect for a non-executable script file (or for any other non-executable file, for that matter).

Only the read (`r`) permission is needed to be able to read a script file.